# What is the best way to pull a remote file or folder from a PSSession (Enter-PSSession)

Tags: powershell, session, file-transfer

I usually work in remote devices from Powershell
using the quick and useful 'Enter-PSSession'

it's a nice option...
replaces well a SSH console session...
and also has some advantages over SSH (has also disadvantages)

but...
I frequently need to **TRANSFER A FILE OR A FOLDER** (pull from remote)...
and found somewhat **ANNOYING TO CREATE A NEW SESSION** (new-session)
and re-enter credentials... etc. etc. ... just to make this copy..

?is there a **MORE CONVENIENT APPROACH**??
aka... a more easy way of doing this file-transfers
from inside the current session???

[For reference, I'll leave  link
 to a discussion about this topic in a MS Forum...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/176718/powershell-copy-file-to-local-machine-after-enter.html)

Comment: Does it have to use a session? `Copy-Item C:\path\to\txt.txt -Destination \\NetBiosName\c$\destination\path`

Comment: Hell, you can even use: `invoke-command -ComputerName "name" -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item \\compname\c$\pathto\txt.txt -Destination C:\local\path` and it will copy over from their system off whichever specified

Answer (score 2):

Create the remote session with `New-PSSession` and use `Copy-Item`'s `-FromSession` parameter:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName remoteComputer
Copy-Item C:\path\on\remote.ext -Destination C:\local\destination\ -FromSession $session
```

You can reuse `$session` for any subsequent copy operations from the same machine

---

Both commands have aliases that make this work with very few keystrokes:

```
$s = nsn remoteComputer
cp file.ext .\ -From $s
```

Comment: yep... that is the way I've been using it... but if I'm in a session created with Enter-PSSession, and want to make some file transfer -> I have to exit and copy... and the recreate the session... and if I have more file transferences to do -> exit again.. and tranfer... and reenter session... and so on.. and so on...

Comment: As the session already exists... and the copy ToSession/FromSession already exits... it will make sense... and will be a huge convenience... if you could made this files transfers transparently,,,

Comment: @ZEE I'm not sure I understand the problem - you don't have to recreate the session afterwards, `Enter-PSSession $someExistingSession` works just fine

Comment: if you are in a session created with "Enter-PSSession $session"... you'll lhave to exit that session to  "Copy ... -FromSession $session"... and enter again the session "Enter-PSSession $session"... to continue your work... it should be a 'avoidable annoyance'...

Comment: @ZEE Correct, not much to be done about that. Another option is to stay in your local session and then use the remote session one comand at a time using `Invoke-Command -Session $session { <# execute this in remote session #> }`

Comment: Of course you can do the job with 2 console windows... if you are in a "Enter-PSSession" session just open a new console... and create the $session variable... and do the Copy-Item... BUT -> the intention is to avoid this...